# Need help to automate below spark logic to fetch column details in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need help to automate below code so that it should automatically pick the header from the table and convert all the header column to row, and then need to perform basic aggregation(Max,Min..etc)

Any clue would be much helpful.

Below I am passing column name manually from the table, picking header from the table and converting it to column.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = sc.parallelize([ \
    Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80), \
    Row(name='Mujkesh', age=10, height=90), \
    Row(name='Ganesh', age=15, height=100)]).toDF()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Test")
df3 = spark.sql("desc Test" )
df4=df.selectExpr("stack(3,'name',bigint(name),'age',bigint(age),'height',bigint(height)) as (col_name,data)").groupBy(col("col_name")).agg(max(col("data")).alias("Max_val"),min(col("data")).alias("Min_val"))
df5=df3.join(df4,['col_name'],'inner').orderBy("col_name").drop(col("comment"))
df5.show()

    Input Data :
    +---+------+-------+
    |age|height|   name|
    +---+------+-------+
    |  5|    80|  Alice|
    | 10|    90|Mujkesh|
    | 15|   100| Ganesh|
    +---+------+-------+
output DATA: 
+--------+---------+-------+-------+
|col_name|data_type|Max_val|Min_val|
+--------+---------+-------+-------+
|     age|   bigint|     15|      5|
|  height|   bigint|    100|     80|
|    name|   string|   null|   null|
+--------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: check  for ```df.describe()``` , it will give you ```count```,```max```,```min```.. & other details for every column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the names of the columns by using -
spark_df.schema.names

You could also try using pivot on that particular column.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is in scala.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- height: integer (nullable = false)
```

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+---+------+
|name   |age|height|
+-------+---+------+
|Alice  |5  |80    |
|Mujkesh|10 |90    |
|Ganesh |15 |100   |
+-------+---+------+
```

```
scala> 
val expr = array(
    df
    .schema
    .map(c => (c.name,c.dataType.typeName)) // column name & its data type
    .map(c => 
        struct(
            lit(c._1).as("column_name"),
            if(c._2 != "string") max(col(c._1)).as("max") else lit(null).cast("int").as("max"),
            if(c._2 != "string") min(col(c._1)).as("min") else lit(null).cast("int").as("min"),
            lit(c._2).as("datatype")
        )
    ):_*
)
```

```
scala> df
.select(expr.as("summary"))
.select(explode($"summary").as("summary"))
.select("summary.*")
.show(false)

+-----------+----+----+--------+
|column_name|max |min |datatype|
+-----------+----+----+--------+
|name       |null|null|string  |
|age        |15  |5   |integer |
|height     |100 |80  |integer |
+-----------+----+----+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas for the logic, but when I am trying to build same logic in python using map (df.schema.map) , getting below error : <AttributeError: 'StructType' object has no attribute 'map'>

Comment: May be you need to use python lambda map.. somthing like map(lambda x : x.name, df.schema)..